# my code doesn't run but shows "Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output" in the terminal. Please help check where i am wrong

Tags: solidity, python, solc, py-solc-x

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

install_solc("0.6.0")

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

# compile Our Solidity

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
print(compiled_sol)
```

Comment: It started displaying this in terminal after i added the install_solc("0.6.0") line. I only added this line because initially when i ran my code it would display "solc 0.6.0 not installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed node.js for windows after which I ran in terminal `npm install -g solc`

After the installations, I ran `python deploy.py` code finally ran!!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to compile your contract in Python environment I recommend you to use Brownie. It will make your life much easier. Basically you will need to just run the `brownie compile` command and thats all.

[Brownie Docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you but i'm new to this and following a course. Still yet to use brownie.